# Unable to load PDF in PdfBox and also unable open it in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using PdfBox to extract information from PDF file, but for some reason I am unable to do load PDF file itself. I tried opening it in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. I am unable to read the file in PdfBox because there is seems some issue with the format of the PDF file. Upon opening it in NotePad++ it gives below content:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

What does this html mean?
I am using `PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(pdfFile)` to load PDF file (`pdfFile` is `ByteArrayInputStream`)

Comment: That is a HTML file. PDF files start with %PDF.

Comment: OK that helps, @TilmanHausherr though size of file is 87KB.